# Number of leaf nodes in n-element red-black trees

Tags: balanced-search-trees

Why the number of (NIL) leaf nodes in n-element red-black trees is n+1?

Comment: This is tree for every full binary tree.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a red-black tree is a full binary tree in which each node is assigned either red or black and the leaves are labeled as **NIL-node** while internal nodes are labeled as **non-NIL node**. In a full binary tree all of the nodes have either 0 or 2 children. Thus, assuming that a full binary tree has `n` internal nodes, the number of leaf nodes will be `n + 1`. So what you are asking is: if red-black tree has `n` **non-NIL nodes** why does it have `n+1` **NIL-nodes** ?